# Using for nested loop, I want to fill my datable to another datatable

Tags: c#

I want to add my `dtbl` data table record into my `DtCloned` data table, but after changing the type of column index 2 then fill it into `dtCloned`, I have an issue filling my record to `dtcloned` after changing the types.

```
DataTable dtCloned = dtbl.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(TimeSpan);

for (int i = 1; i <= dtbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dtCloned.NewRow();

    for (int j = 0; j < dtbl.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        DataColumn dtc = new DataColumn();

        if (j == 2)
        {
            //dtc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Datetime");
            //dtCloned.Columns.Add(dtc);
            string s = dtbl.Rows[i][dtbl.Columns[j]].ToString();//12/31/1899 10:00:00 AM Tables[2].Rows[j][Model.Tables[2].Columns[i]]
            string FTime;
            FTime = s.Substring(11);
            DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(FTime.ToString());
            string FTime2 = dt1.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(FTime2, "HH:mm:ss tt", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
            string FTT = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            row[i] = FTT;//DateTime.ParseExact(FTime, "HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                    
        }
        else
            row[i] = dtbl.Rows[i][dtbl.Columns[j]];
    }

    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just adding a new column to the dataTable pulled locally of the destination type expected, then do foreach() of every row and update the one column you wanted added.

```
dtbl.Columns.Add("YourTimeSpan", typeof(timespan));

foreach( DataRow dr in dtbl.Rows )
{
    dr["YourTimeSpan"] = WhateverYouAreTryingToDo;
    // the bulk of code that does all your date / tryparse conversion stuff.
}
```

So first, add the column of a time-stamp data type.  Leaves original table alone so you dont have to duplicate everything.  Now, by cycling through each DataRow in the DataTable, you have the row object.

By referencing the `dr["YourTimeSpan"]`, you are referring to the column by its column name instead of ordinal representation.  For your original data, if you know that column name you could refer to it that way too such as `dr["OriginalDateTimeColumn"]`, but you could still do via dr[2] if you wanted to keep the 0-based ordinal column reference.

Now I am not sure what you are really doing.  Trying to convert a string to a date/time based on known format?  But if the original value of the cell IS a date/time, you should be able to work directly from it AS a datetime field and apply its normal `.ToString()` formatting options.

If you can EDIT YOUR EXISTING question with details of the original column data types, (string vs datetime), then you dont need to do conversions.  If the originating data is coming from some SQL database, and the original data type is of a date/time or timestamp type of column, I would suggest adding the formatted value you want directly from the SQL engine vs you trying to keep parsing it here.

FEEDBACK

So, your existing table, column #3 (ordinal column 2 when zero-based) IS a date/time column.  And you are just trying to convert it to a single string in 24-hr clock format?  So 3:27pm = 15:27 via 24-hr clock?

Here is a sample of checking/confirming data type you are working with.  I just put a breakpoint in the program when it got to my table and columns in-place and I added a blank row. So add to the watch window your "dtbl.Columns[2]" and expand it. Check to see/confirm if your column's data type is already that of DateTime structure. If so you don't need to do conversions.

[image: Sample Breakpoint on detecting column type]

If the value for the data type *IS* DateTime, and you only care about the string representation of it as 24hr, simple enough via the loop I has above, but instead, you would just add a column of a STRING data type, not timespan.

Then you could do

```
   if( dr[2] is System.DBNull )
      // no such value in the row date/time column
      dr["YourTimeSpan"] = ""; 
   else
      // there IS a datetime value to work with.
      // "HH" upper case is specifically 24-hr clock, then minute and second
      dr["YourTimeSpan"] = dr[2].ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Note, that by this measure, it will have your extra column to the LAST column on the data row, but still simpler to work with than full cloning and doing crazy parse testing. Please let me know if helps and if you have any other issues.

If string is the final data type, just make sure you add the column as

```
dtbl.Columns.Add("YourTimeSpan", typeof(string));
```

instead of `typeof(timespan)` in the original example.

Comment: I am uploading excel file at the time of uploading the in the file index 2 is the datetime format like '01/01/1989 10:15:00 AM' but i want change this column data to like '10:15:00' this before add to new DataTable '10:15:00' means in 24 hours format there's the conversion has been placed but i am unAble to fill that data to the table if you understand so guide me.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib, see my revised answer